# How to get uncommon objects from two list of diferent objects

Tags: java, java-stream

I have two lists

```
List<Foo> foolist = getAll();
List<Bar> barList = getAll();

class Foo {
    String name;
    String age;
    ....
    // more fields
}

class Bar {
    String barName;
    int codeBar;
    ....
    // more field
}
```

We can make relationship between them with age<->codeBar and name<->barName
I want to get Bar objects that are not into foolist, 
How can it be done using streams?

I see examples using stream().filter(list::contains) but it is not valid in this case.

Can anyone point me into right direction?

Thanks to everyone. 
I'm looking something like this:
   `barList.stream().filter(b->fooList.stream().anyMatch(f->!b.getBarName().equalsIgnoreCase(f.getName) && b.getCodeBar() == Integer.valueOf(age))).collect(Collectors.toList());`

I don't know yet if it's right

Comment: What does "make a relationship between them" mean exactly?

Comment: I mean that we can use theese fields to compare and know if they are equals.

Comment: How do you want to compare `String age` with `int codeBar`? They will never be equal. And honestly I would recommend converting objects of one class to the other.

Comment: In your logic, if both `age.equals(codeBar.toString()) && name.equals(barName)` then they are equal?

Comment: age is a String but could be parsed to an integer, it is not important, if you want i could change it.

Comment: Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn that's right

Comment: @Juan see my edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Foo> fooList = asList(new Foo("1", "1"), new Foo("2", "2"), new Foo("3", "3"));
    List<Bar> barList = asList(new Bar("4", 4), new Bar("3", 3), new Bar("5", 5));

    Set<Blah> fooSet = fooList.stream().map(Main::fooToBlah).collect(toCollection(HashSet::new));
    Set<Blah> barSet = barList.stream().map(Main::barToBlah).collect(toCollection(HashSet::new));

    barList.stream()
            .filter(bar -> !fooSet.contains(barToBlah(bar)))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    fooList.stream()
            .filter(foo -> !barSet.contains(fooToBlah(foo)))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}

static Blah fooToBlah(Foo foo) {
    return new Blah(foo.name, foo.age);
}

static Blah barToBlah(Bar bar) {
    return new Blah(bar.barName, "" + bar.codeBar);
}

static class Blah {
    String name;
    String age;

    public Blah(String name, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        ...
    }
}
```

1. Take all `Foo` objects and convert them to `Blah` (name it appropriately of course) - this is needed because `Foo` has other fields that we don't care about.
2. Put `Blah` objects into a `HashSet` so that you don't end up with `O(n*m)` time complexity. You could do just `collect(toSet())`, but I prefer to be explicit about it here as it is important for performance.
3. Go over `Bar` objects and if an object is not in the above set, that's the uncommon `Bar` object. It needs to be converted to `Blah` and unfortunately you cannot use `Stream.map` as in the end it should still be `Stream<Bar>`, not `Stream<Blah>`.
4. Repeat above three steps for the other list to find all uncommon `Foo` objects.

Remember that `equals` and `hashCode` methods are needed on `Blah` class. `Foo` and `Bar` classes don't need them.

---

**EDIT:**

You can convert the following code

```
Set<Blah> fooSet = fooList.stream().map(Main::fooToBlah).collect(toCollection(HashSet::new));

barList.stream()
        .filter(bar -> !fooSet.contains(barToBlah(bar)))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

into something like this

```
barList.stream()
        .filter(bar -> fooList.stream()
                .map(Main::fooToBlah)
                .noneMatch(foo -> foo.equals(barToBlah(bar)))
        )
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

or even remove `Blah` class completely

```
barList.stream()
        .filter(bar -> fooList.stream().noneMatch(foo -> Objects.equals(foo.name, bar.barName) && Objects.equals(foo.age, "" + bar.codeBar)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

but you will end up with much worse time complexity and then there is also a question of readability.

Comment: `Bar` would need to implement `Comparable<Bar>`, and `Foo` would need to implement `Comparable<Foo>`  in order for this to work, yes?

Comment: @KevinAnderson No, you don't need `Comparable` here. This interface would be needed if you used `TreeSet`, but this would have worse performance than `HashSet` in this case.

Comment: I think you didn't consider the fact that both `Foo` and `Bar` contains other attribute when `hashCode` and `equals`

Answer (score 2):

A naive solution is to loop through both lists. Assuming you can formulate your equality condition as `BiPredicate<Foo, Bar>`:

```
for (Bar bar: bars) {
    boolean foundEqualFoo = false;
    for(Foo foo: foos) {
        if (predicate.test(foo, bar)) {
            foundEqualFoo = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!foundEqualFoo) {
        barsNotInFoos.add(bar);
    }
}
```

That's `O(n*m)` time complexity.

A better solution would be to define a key class like `FooBarKey` which would hold `name` and `age` and implement `equals(...)` and `hashCode()` correctly. You could then do the following:

```
Map<FooBarKey, List<Bar>> barsByKey = bars
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        FooBarKey::ofBar,
        HashMap::new,
        Collectors.toList()));

Set<FooBarKey> fooKeys = foos
    .stream()
    .map(FooBarKey::ofFoo)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

barsByKey.keySet().removeAll(fooKeys);

Set<Bar> uncommonBars = barsByKey
    .values()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Few notes on the solution:

- I think creating `Map<FooBarKey, ...>` is reasonable here to avoid constantly creating new `FooBarKey` instances for the same `Bar`s.
- A multi-map `Map<FooBarKey, List<Bar>>` is needed since there may be bars with the same key in the list.
- `HashMap::new` and `HashSet::new` suppliers are used where applicable to make sure hash tables are used to guarantee `O(1)` on corresponding operations.

That should be `O(2*n + m)`.

Comment: This's neat. But work. Unless OP try to filter out a big list

Comment: Doesn't use streams (so technically not on point), but solves the problem anyway.  Therefore doubly correct.  Only wish I could have upvoted twice.

Comment: @KevinAnderson OP didn't say that they want a stream solution (they mentioned that they saw solutions using streams) and honestly using streams is not always more readable than classic loops.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I read " How can it be done using streams?" as a requirement, but maybe it was OP's expression of skepticism of a stream solution.  If the latter, well done OP for not falling under the "spell of the stream".

Comment: @KevinAnderson You are right, I missed that part :)